# Move to other part of javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, authentication

I am creating a data storage site with html, css, and javascript. On the login, It uses an if/else inside of a function. An example of what I need is below:

```
$('.activelogin').click(function(){
//get the username
//get the password
if (username === 'myName') {
document.cookie = 'succesful=true';
//go to more code
} else {
document.cookie = 'successful=false';
}
//more code
```

How do I get to `//more code` from `//go to more code`?

Comment: If you replace "teleport" with "function", you're golden.

Comment: I mean there is no "teleport", but there are functions, that can be called where you choose etc.

Comment: `I am creating a database with html, css, and javascript. ` makes no sense in my mind...what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am creating a way to store date and allow me and my friends to send and recieve on it too, and well as storing permanent info on it.

Comment: You can't do that with cookies? Anyway, learn how functions work first -> https://jsfiddle.net/0yjhj9h1/

Comment: @adeneo is correct...write a function and call it in your code.  For example:  `function myLogin() { //function code  }`   and then call it with:  `myLogin();`

Comment: Two words: function variables.